# The performance of Drupal on Azure

Tags: azure, drupal-7, captcha, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I have the main page that loaded very long time (6-10 seconds) because it contains a form with captcha. The performance of the webapp + mysql (venus) is very bad... Drupal does not cache pages with a captcha, so recreate a page and does not load from redis cache. How best to resolve this performance issue?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Redis in Azure Web Apps. Please see the following guide for more information:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-connect-to-redis-using-memcache-protocol/

If you have a slow start up time only on the first request, you can try enabling always on. To enable always on: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

For further speed up tips, please see this blog entry: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/. Although it is targeted to Wordpress the same tips are applicable to Drupal.